# The method '*' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: *(2)

Tags: flutter, methods, null

I really have no idea what is causing this error. I tried removing the function sunday() because I thought it may be causing the problem but the issue persisted. I also tried removing selectableDayPredicate but the issue still persisted. My widget tree is a bit long, sorry for the long read. Any help is appreciated! Here is my code:

```
class TaskScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TaskScreenState createState() => _TaskScreenState();
}

class _TaskScreenState extends State<TaskScreen> {
  DateTime sunday() {
    _date = DateTime.now();
    if (_date.weekday == 1) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 6);
    }
    if (_date.weekday == 2) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 5);
    }
    if (_date.weekday == 3) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 4);
    }
    if (_date.weekday == 4) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 3);
    }
    if (_date.weekday == 5) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 2);
    }
    if (_date.weekday == 6) {
      _date = DateTime.utc(_date.year, _date.month, _date.weekday + 1);
    }
    return _date;
  }

  final searchFocusNode = FocusNode();
  DateTime _date = DateTime.now();

  Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    DateTime _datePicker = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
            accentColor: Color.fromRGBO(56, 85, 144, 1),
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                primary: const Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1)),
            buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
          ),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      initialDate: sunday(),
      firstDate: DateTime(1947),
      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
      selectableDayPredicate: (day) => day.weekday == 7 ? true : false,
    );
    if (_datePicker != null && _datePicker != _date) {
      setState(() {
        _date = _datePicker;
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 2),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.search),
                onPressed: () {},
                iconSize: 40,
                focusNode: searchFocusNode,
                color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth * 80,
                child: TextFormField(
                  focusNode: searchFocusNode,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Search",
                  ),
                  onFieldSubmitted: (_) {},
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 0.1,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.date_range,
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                  ),
                  iconSize: 40,
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                       _selectDate(context);
                    });
                  }),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    width: SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth * 80,
                    child: TextFormField(
                      initialValue: "${_date.year}-${_date.month}-${_date.day}",
                      cursorColor: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                      readOnly: true,
                      onTap: () {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectDate(context);
                        });
                      },
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Date",
                        hintText: "${_date.year}-${_date.month}-${_date.day}",
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                          width: 2,
                        )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 2,
          ),
          Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5)),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth * 3,
                        vertical: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight,
                      ),
                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth * 7.5,
                        vertical: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 2,
                      ),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Project Name: ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.5),
                              ),
                              Text("Telecom Egypt"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 0.5),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Task Code: ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text("#1235"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 0.5),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Project Manager: ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text("Khaled Khalifa"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 0.5),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Time: ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text("8 Hours"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding:
                                EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 0.5),
                          ),
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Priority: ",
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Text("1"),
                            ],
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight,
                          ),
                          Row(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              Icon(
                                Icons.remove_red_eye,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.edit,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth),
                              ),
                              Icon(
                                Icons.comment,
                                color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsets.all(SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                children: [
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.clear,
                                    color: Colors.red,
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                        SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth),
                                  ),
                                  Icon(
                                    Icons.check,
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(56, 85, 144, 1),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ))
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(66, 87, 184, 1),
                          width: 1,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    index == 2
                        ? SizedBox(
                            height: SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight * 7,
                          )
                        : SizedBox()
                  ],
                );
              },
              itemCount: 3,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help if you could only post the part of the code that is causing the issue. Side note I noticed at the top of your code in the ```sunday()``` function you only handle days 1-6, while there are 7 days, are you missing day 0 or day 7 or maybe this is on purpose?

Please set the debugger to catch all unhandled exceptions, run the code, and find out the exact spot the bug is happening to clean up this question.

Comment: @augustKimo Thing is I have no idea which part is causing the error. And yes, the 7th day is left on purpose. When I run the code, it just brings up a red screen. No chance to even debug. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: What code editor are you using? You can always debug, using the debugger it will pinpoint the line of code the error is happening at.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have posted, it says the `*` is called on `null`, meaning there is a `multiplication` operation carried on a `null` variable.

In the code you have a variable:

```
SizeConfig.gridSizeHeight
```

AND

```
SizeConfig.gridSizeWidth
```

which is `multiplied` in a lot of places for sizing purposes. The value of of that variable is `null` at some point, which might be causing the exception.

Please check the `SizeConfig` and make sure the variable `gridSizeHeight` OR `gridSizeWidth` is not `null`.